# Question: Block id h1 font size for phones

Tags: css, media-queries, squarespace

I'm trying to implement a code on my Squarespace website's homepage to make the 'Soph and Mat' [www.thedistancelive.com](https://www.thedistancelive.com) larger on mobile only.
I've tried the following:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:640px) {
       #block-yui_3_17_2_1_1594350948064_7952 {
        font-size: 35px;
        line-height: 35px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top:10px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
  #block-yui_3_17_2_1_1594350948064_7952, .index-section-wrapper h1 {
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top:10px;
  }
}
```

The margin-top/bottom work but the font size is not budging.

Can anyone help, please?
Thank you x

Comment: I think it's overwritten by other CSS code, well you can use `font-size:80px !important;` or increase the specificity of the selector

Comment: hi thanks for coming back to me, do you know where i can find this, please?

Comment: use the dev-tools and see if it's overwritten,(your font-size will be cut by a grey dash)

Comment: and check the comment above again

Comment: i tried the !important but that didn't work either, thanks though. this has come up? @media only screen and (max-width: 640px)
.index-section-wrapper .content.has-main-media h1:not(.OT_title) {
    font-size: 36px !important;
} witha. line through the font size..

Comment: yeah, that means it's overwritten, try  `.sqs-block html-block sqs-block-html > .sqs-block-content > h1 { font-size: 80px;} `

Comment: https://csswizardry.com/2014/07/hacks-for-dealing-with-specificity/

Comment: thank you, where do i put this, please? sorry i'm a complete newb here :)

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
 .sqs-block html-block sqs-block-html > .sqs-block-content > h1 {
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top:10px;
  }
}

Comment: no sorry the margins worked again but the size didn't x

Comment: read the article above, to get right specificity

Comment: ok, thanks for your help :) x

Answer (score 0):

The issue has to do with CSS being overridden by a rule that is both higher specificity and using `!important`. That is not atypical in Squarespace, where the rules are written based on style and template selections made in the back-end, creating CSS rules with relatively high specificity.

In such cases, one should use the [browser developer tools/inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools#The_Inspector_DOM_explorer_and_CSS_editor) to view the rule in question. Then, a rule of equal or greater specificity can be be written to override the default CSS.

To do that:

1. While viewing the page, narrow your browser's width until mobile styles are enabled.
2. Right-click on the element in question. In this case, that is the H1.
3. Select "Inspect" (or "Inspect Element" in Firefox and other browsers).
4. In one of the panels, you'll see the CSS that applies to the target element (the H1 in this case). Find the active rule that is setting font size.

[image]

5. Based on that rule, write your own rule of equal or greater specificity and priority. Something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:640px) {
  .index-section-wrapper .content.has-main-media #block-yui_3_17_2_1_1594350948064_7952 h1:not(.OT_title) {
    font-size: 35px !important;
  }
}
```

6. Add the rule via [Custom CSS / CSS Editor](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545567-Using-the-CSS-Editor).

There are other ways to write a rule of greater specificity than the example above. It is just one example.